# unexpected behavior when using append method on python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I am trying to update the value for a particular key in a dictionary. However, for some reason, all the keys in the dictionary are updated with that value. I don't know what part of the code throws out this issue.

Below is the code

```
# get unique values to use as keys
array = list(assignments.values())
new_key = list(set([x for l in array for x in l]))
print('key list is {}'.format(new_key) + '\n')

# initiate a dictionary with empty lists as values
d=dict.fromkeys(new_key,[])
print('empty dictionary is {}'.format(d) + '\n')

# add values of 'Monday' to new dictionary key of Jen
d['Jeh'].append('Monday')

print(d)
```

Here's the output from the code block above  -- as you can see in the last line of the output, instead of having 'Monday' as the value for 'Jeh' key only, all other keys are also updated with 'Monday'.

```
key list is ['Ben', 'Chinmay', 'Samuel', 'Michael', 'Shishir', 'Jeh', 'Rachel', 'Evan', 'Yandi', 'Raghav']

empty dictionary is {'Ben': [], 'Chinmay': [], 'Samuel': [], 'Michael': [], 'Shishir': [], 'Jeh': [], 'Rachel': [], 'Evan': [], 'Yandi': [], 'Raghav': []}

{'Ben': ['Monday'], 'Chinmay': ['Monday'], 'Samuel': ['Monday'], 'Michael': ['Monday'], 'Shishir': ['Monday'], 'Jeh': ['Monday'], 'Rachel': ['Monday'], 'Evan': ['Monday'], 'Yandi': ['Monday'], 'Raghav': ['Monday']}
```

Comment: I think that when you use `dict.fromkeys` it assigns the same list to all the keys. Because list is a reference type, all the keys would refer to the same list (the same memory location).
Hence, updating one key updates all of them.

Comment: Try to initialize the dict woth a for-loop, and it would probably solve it

Comment: @SagiZiv **everything** is a "reference type" in Python. But yes, this is the issue. OP, use `{k: [] for k in new_key}`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you!!